# How to force an item into a fixed position on the screen?

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, android-linearlayout

How can I place an item on the screen in a way that it doesn't move even if I scrolled ?  I am using a LinearLayout.

Comment: Why do you mention that this is an **history tab**? Does this affect the question?

Comment: @Baruch no not really . I just need help with placing an item on the screen in a way that it doesnt move even if I scrolled .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're open to wrapping your LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout, this will work and is flexible in that you can make most any type of view (e.g., Button) fixed.

**Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="false">
      <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/txtScrollingText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
      </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="This Button Is Fixed"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Use a [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button) would work.

When you Create a new simple view Xamarin.Android project, there is `FloatingActionButton` sample in the `activity_main.axml`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

And in the activity, you can customize the `click` event.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
fab.Click += FabOnClick;
```

Here is a gif:

[image: screen]: